# Bring custom derive macro into namespace via plugin

Tags: rust, rust-macros

Is it possible to reduce the boilerplate in using a library (as the library author) from:

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#![plugin(myplugin)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate myplugin_derive;

#[derive(MyPlugin)]
// ...
```

to something more like:

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#![plugin(myplugin)]

#[derive(MyPlugin)]
// ...
```

That is, since I know anyone using `myplugin` wants to use `#[derive(MyPlugin)]`, is there a way of bringing `MyPlugin` into scope with `#![plugin(myplugin)]` only?